# Way to refer a column within a same name under difference merged cell?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

im kinda new to pandas and stuck at how to refer a column within same name under different merged column. here some example which problem im stuck about. i wanna refer a database from worker at company C. but if im define this excel as df and
dfcompanyAworker=df[Worker]
it wont work

is there any specific way to define a database within identifical column like this ?

heres the table
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Y6gp.png

thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first read the dataset that will be used, then set the shape for example I use excel format

```
dfcompanyAworker = pd.read_excel('Worker', skiprows=1, header=[1,2], index_col=0, skipfooter=7)
dfcompanyAworker
```

where:

- skiprows=1 to ignore the title row in the data
- header=[1, 2] is a list because we have multilevel columns, namely Category (Company) and other data
- index_col=0 to make the Date column an ​​index for easier processing and analysis
- skipfooter=7 to ignore the footer at the end of the data line

You can follow or try the steps as I made the following